# Android v2.2-2.3.5: WebView : loadDataWithBaseURL : will only load page once

Tags: android, webview, loaddata

When I'm loading a page using `.loadData` or `.loadDataWithBaseURL`, the system will load a page once.

After that, subsequent calls do not work.

In 4.0.3, if I were to call the function a second time with new data, it does change.

How can I fix this for 2.2+? Do I destroy the webview and create a new one?

```
webView1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://", page, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
webView1.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In loadDataWithBaseURL, set the last parameter to the URL where that data came from, instead of `null`.

Comment: The page didn't come from anywhere... I'm using HTML generated programmatically.

Comment: If you put something there, like "file://" (doesn't really matter), it will add that element to the history stack (when you click the back button), and you'll get a callback to shouldOverrideUrlLoading in your WebViewClient.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `"file:///"`. You just missed one slash.