# Android WebView loadWithBaseURL

Tags: android, css, webview

I am wondering how do I set the path for WebViews loadWithBaseURL correctly.

What I want to do is, to load html in a webview, that uses resources that are stored on the external storage.

For Example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>body{ background-image:url(beach.jpg); }</style> 
</head>
<body> 
<img src="football.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Where beach.jpg and ball.jpg are stored directly in the "root" directory of the phones external storage (/sdcard/beach.jpg and /sdcard/ball.jpg)

So I tried to load the content as follows:

```
String html = "<html> ... example from above ... </html>";
String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://" + base, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

However the path seems to be wrong, because I can't see the image in the webview.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled file access on the webview?

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

Additionally, if you are constructing the HTML yourself - you might consider using full paths for the images.

```
String html = "<html>... <img src=\"file://"+base+"/football.jpg\" />";
```

Comment: Damn, webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); solved the problem ... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you give **internet permission**?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

These may also help..

- [Android webview loadDataWithBaseURL how load images from assets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374553/android-webview-loaddatawithbaseurl-how-load-images-from-assets)
- http://myexperiencewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/09/android-loaddatawithbaseurl.html
- [Android v2.2-2.3.5: WebView : loadDataWithBaseURL : will only load page once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960443/android-v2-2-2-3-5-webview-loaddatawithbaseurl-will-only-load-page-once)